# Running SpringBootTest keeps raising error "Port 8080 already in use" after adding test/resources/application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, automated-tests

Because we are creating tests that do not need to access the Postgres database, we are migrating our tests to use H2 storage. We've created a separate `application.properties` in `src/test/resources/application.properties` overriding all values from our default `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
spring.liquibase.change-log=
security.oidc_domain=123
security.jwt_key=123
api_url=http://localhost:8080
encryption.secret=123
security.debug=false
allowed_hosts=*
```

We have the following CoreApplication file which boots the Spring App:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class CoreApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(CoreApplication.class);

        application.run(args);
    }

    public ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(args);
        context = SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And this is our test file:

```java
@SpringBootTest()
class CoreApplicationTests {

    @Test()
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

When we run this test (via IntelliJ IDEA) we get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8080 is already in use
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
```

Before we added the custom application.properties in test is was working perfectly, but was hitting a connection limit to PostgreSQL because of the amount of tests, so it looks like this is caused by the application.properties override in tests folder.

Comment: Are you running the application and the tests at the same time? If that's the case, you can override the port by `server.port=8001` for example.

Comment: Something in "the machine" is running on port 8080. The test application tried to start its web server but could not bind on port 8080 because something else is using it, therefore the web server threw an error. Do you have some other local host running of some other app you have forgotten. I have four different localhost machines I can use in my machine. Apache, glassfish,wildfly,tomcat and variants.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

to get a random available port for your test.
If you need that random port in your test class you can use

```
  @LocalServerPort
  private String port;
```

to get the port into a variable.

Aside that, I would use spring profiles to use a "test" profile `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` for tests and adding `@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")` to my test class.

Comment: You can also use `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE` instead of `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` if you are just testing a controller and do not need a port.